# Failed to open stream problem with defining a constant and path

Tags: php

I have a problem with the path, I created a function that contains the sending of the path of a specific file intended for the user. Init.php contains the definition of the path and the constant.

Warning: require_once(//opt/lampp/htdocs/gallery123/admin/includes/init.php/init.php/admin/includes/functions.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/gallery123/admin/includes/init.php on line 22

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '//opt/lampp/htdocs/gallery123/admin/includes/init.php/init.php/admin/includes/functions.php' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/gallery123/admin/includes/init.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gallery123/includes/header.php(1): require_once() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/gallery123/photo.php(1): include('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/gallery123/admin/includes/init.php on line 22

init.php

```
<?php 




defined('DS') ? null : define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);



defined('SITE_ROOT') ? null : define('SITE_ROOT', DS . __FILE__ . DS . 'init.php');





defined('INCLUDES_PATH') ? null : define('INCLUDES_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'admin'.DS.'includes');


defined('IMAGES_PATH') ? null : define('IMAGES_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'admin'.DS.'images');


require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."functions.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."config.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."database.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."db_object.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."user.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."photo.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."comment.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."session.php");
require_once(INCLUDES_PATH.DS."paginate.php");


 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
<?php 
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/yourpath';
```

You can do a `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` to see your path.